# Copy byte array to varbinary in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, linq-to-sql, insert-update

I am trying to copy the arriving `byte[] buffer` to a varbinary(max) value in sql table and I want to refresh the table after the copy.

Th `fl.Data` parameter in `Buffer.BlockCopy` should be an array but my destination is a varbinary.

This is my code:

```
public Boolean WriteBlobsToDB(byte[] buffer,int id,string fileName,string fileType,string user,string md5)
{
    FileList fl = new FileList(); //FileList is the name of my table
    fl.FileName = fileName;
    fl.FileType = fileType;
    fl.MD5 = md5;
    fl.UserID = user;
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer,0,fl.Data,offset,count);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your destination is not a "varbinary". It's a LINQ `Binary`.

```
fl.Data = buffer;
```